# Where does Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 store "Do not ask again" answer?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, settings, file-location

I am looking for the config file(s) or registry key(s) that Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition stores the "Do not ask again" values.

I've pressed the space bar at the "wrong" time when tabbing through the find/replace results dialog, accidentally selecting the "Do not ask again" checkbox. That's one example of something I'm trying desperately to undo.

Any ideas? I've uninstalled and reinstalled MSVSCE and that didn't help. I didn't think it would.

Answer (score 0):

I have Professional Edition but I would guess it will be the same in Community Edition.

Go to Tools->Options. The settings are likely in there.

For example, for the "Find and Replace" options, go to Environment->Find and Replace. There are checkboxes to turn the display of messages and warnings on and off. Other settings should be in similar locations.

The "Search" bar at the top will be useful for tracking down the setting you need to change.

Comment: For some reason, all the informational boxes I was concerned about have re-appeared, and I'm frightened to tempt fate and turn them off to test this, but that does look like exactly what I wanted. I'll remember your tip when it happens accidentally again.  Thanks.